# Rewrite domain using htaccess and remove subfolder from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have multiple domains which I want subfolders for using `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.html [L]
```

But this means URLs can still contain the subfolder: `example.com/subfolder/img/file.png`. How do I stop `/subfolder` from being accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new rule to remove `/subfolder/` from you URLs like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subfolder/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ subfolder/index.html [L]
```

Comment: I can still access `example.com/subfolder/img/file.png`. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: First redirect will redirect `/subfolder/img/file.png` to `/img/file.png`

Comment: I can still access the file with the subfolder in the URL.

Comment: It is tested and working rule. Do you have .htaccess inside `/subfolder/` also OR more rules than shown here.